# how to scale the drawable to fit the screen

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

in my project I want to draw my drawable to the screen to fit its height and width , and then I want to draw other things on its center . The problem is when I want to draw it , it not shows fit to the screen , I have tried many things but nothing work for me. 
I know my question is not clear so shortly asking that how to fit the image to fit the background using canvas.drawmethod()
here is what I am using

```
 final Drawable dial = mDial;
        int w = dial.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int h = dial.getIntrinsicHeight();

        boolean scaled = false;

        if (availableWidth < w || availableHeight < h) {
            scaled = true;
            float scale = Math.min((float) availableWidth / (float) w,
                    (float) availableHeight / (float) h);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scale, scale, x, y);
            Log.d("Scaling the width and height","here we go");
        }

        if (changed) {
            dial.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
            Log.d("bounds have been changed","here we go");
        }
        dial.draw(canvas);
```

please help

Comment: dial.setBounds(0, 0, availableWidth, availableHeight); dial.draw(canvas)

Comment: your comment works thanks . you should post it as a answer